# Bash ! causes command to be recalled from history

Tags: regex, bash, iptables

I'm adding a rule to iptables however since i'm using a port exclusion with ! it seems to be egreping the command from history.

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-ports !80,!443
```

What i get is:

```
-bash: !80: event not found
```

before that it was egrepping a command earlier onto this command

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports !443
```

output was

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports egrep  "47443|47080" netstat_*
iptables v1.4.21: invalid port/service `egrep' specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

any ideas how i can stop it escaping my command?

Comment: You can try disabling the `!` in bash. See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3748

Comment: In the extreme, you can disable history expansion althogether with `set +H`. You can always reenable it with `set -H` if you actually want it.

Comment: Cheers this resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation mark is part of history expansion in bash.
You need to escape it either by wrapping around with single quotes or with backslashes.

So you can escape the exclamation marks as

```
--destination-ports '!80,!443'
--destination-ports \!80,\!443
```

But I suspect whether it is a correct way of a port exclusion.
You can try instead:

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --destination-ports 80,443
```

and also check it from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/769814/how-to-block-all-ports-except-80-443-with-iptables)

Comment: using single quotes fails with


ds04sa01:~ # iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports '!80,!443'
iptables v1.4.21: invalid port/service `!80' specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.


 iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports \!80,\!443
iptables v1.4.21: invalid port/service `!80' specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

!Akif

Answer (score 2):

Just quote it. This will prevent bash from treating `!` as the history expansion character.

```
$ ... --destination-ports '!80,!443'
```

Incidentally, if you run `history` at the bash prompt, you will get a listing of previous commands along with their numbers, and that will tell you what `!<number>` (unquoted) would be interpreted as. For example,

```
$ history
...
25157  echo
25158  history
$ echo !25158
echo history
history
```

Here `!25158` is equivalent to `history`. For more information read the section on "History" in the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 0):

You mean you **want** the exclamation escaped, I believe.

```
$ anycmd '!80' 'siNGLe quo** contain $crazy stuff'
```